# Memory leaking recursive javascript functions in IE,FF,GoogleChrome

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1 id="t">Initial</h1>
            <script>
                var cnt=0;
                setTimeout("addCounter()",100);
                addCounter=function(){
                    ++cnt;
                    if (cnt>1000000) cnt=0;
                    document.getElementById('t').firstChild.nodeValue='Counter: #'+(cnt);
                    setTimeout("addCounter()",100);
                }
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run this sample code in Internet Explorer/Firefox/Chrome, the memory usage increases until the browser/os runs out of memory and the browser crashes!

Any one can help me to rewrite the code that not wast memory? Or I have report it as a bug for browser developer?

Comment: Where's your end condition? This is an infinite loop.

Comment: hey @wylie ... Sadeq question exactly is same ... if we create loop in js ... why browser didn't kill process ?

Comment: @Wylie: I think the question is if the loop isn't creating anything lasting, why would it runs out of memory? Isn't gc supposed to recycle temp object?

Comment: @Sadeq: This code actually runs perfectly for me, having only tested it in chrome. That being said, if you just want to increment something every 100ms until the user closes the window, consider using `setInterval(addCounter, 100)`. See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setinterval). Another performance issue is that you have `"addcounter()"` in quotes, meaning that it gets passed to `eval()` which is incredibly slow. If you pass the function directly, it will get executed faster.

Comment: I used this code to simulate/test my real problem with memory leakage! I know this is not good code in performance. In real work, I have several different timer that change content of a page using AJAX queries and this cause memory leak. If I do every things except replace element value with new ones, there is not any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I increased memory of test machine, I found that after a while the memory usage did not increase any more! It seem the garbage collector (or any thing that is responsible for real free unused memory) is not optimized for low memory systems (like which one I used im my first tests)
In fact Chrome after spending about 50M is ok now, IE 9 after 30M. and I did not check FF yet!

Answer (score 3):

This seems stop the out-of-control memory usage:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1 id="t">Initial</h1>
            <script>
                var cnt=0;
                setTimeout(addCounter,100);
                addCounter=function(){
                    ++cnt;
                    if (cnt>1000000) cnt=0;
                    document.getElementById('t').firstChild.nodeValue='Counter: #'+(cnt);
                    setTimeout(addCounter,100);
                }
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Don't use `setTimeout` with a string. It's bad practice for many reasons, and *apparently* increases memory usage (*Disclaimer: I'm no expert on `setTimeout`*).

Comment: +1 for getting rid of the string usage in the `setTimeout` call, which would otherwise call `eval`, a complete waste.

Comment: As I said above, this is a code to simulate what in real code happen.

Comment: Did you try changing your `setTimeout`s to function references instead of strings?

Answer (score 0):

I think browser must have something like memory manager and nicer system and check each process for abandon leak memory and if each script leak any memory, browser must kill script or alarm and then kill it.

- https://wiki.mozilla.org/Performance/MemShrink
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=174359
- etc ...

ps: this script can use as xss code :D

Comment: About BUG URL, it is not CPU abusing nor performance. It is about memory leak. thank you about MeMShrink link, I have read it.

Comment: @sadeq its only example to say firefox and etc can be misunderstand problem :D

Answer (score -1):

Remove `setTimeout("addCounter()",100);` from function body